# How do I pass data to different routes using Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm creating a web application that requires a user to register/login, and once they've done that, they're taken to their "account page" where their account information is available for them to see.

I'm using MongoDB, Mongoose, and Passport.

I have my post route:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
  User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, foundUser){
    if(foundUser){
      //found user in database
       const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  req.login(user, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          if(user){
            res.redirect("/user");
          } else {
            res.render("home", {failedAttempt: true});
          }
        }
      })(req, res);
    }
  });
    } else {
      //user does not exist
      console.log("the user does not exist here");
      res.render("home", {failedAttempt: true})
    }
  });
});
```

I would like to be able to pass the database info for that particular user to the "/user" route, but I don't know how.  How can I make it so that once the user is redirected to root/user, I can then pull up the info on their database?

Comment: See [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) and learn about the general concept of server-side session objects.  This is how you keep data for a specific user that each request handler can use on behalf of that same user.  Keep in mind that for server scalability reasons, you would typically draw a balance between how much "state" you keep in memory for every active user vs. just getting the data on demand from the database when needed for a new request.  Each app has to draw it's own proper point of balance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Express Middleware. This allows you to do some processing first to pull out the user info and then pass the resulting data to your route.

Read all about it:
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html